# rendered script display inside body template django

Tags: django, render

Sorry for my bad english.
I use

```
{% ishout.js %}
```

inside **head** to render scripts file in django template but they display as string

```
"<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:5500/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:5500/client/ishout.client.js"></script>"
```

and inside **body** not inside **head**.
And other scripts after that are displayed in body too.

I searched and find out by encoding but i cannot find how to fix it.

**UPDATE**
This is views.py file

```
@login_required
def home(request):
    users = User.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id)
    v = RequestContext(request, {'users':users})
    # return render(request, 'home.html', {'users':users})
    return render_to_response('home.html', v)
```

This is home.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Home</title>
    {% load drealtimetags %}
    {% ishout_js %}
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Dashboard</h1>
    {% for user in users %}
        {{ user.first_name }}<a href="/alert/?user={{ user.id }}">Alert (Hello)</a>
    {% empty %}
        <b>No user found</b>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE 2:**
This is page source

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Home</title>


    &lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot; src=&quot;http://localhost:5500/socket.io/socket.io.js&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
    &lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot; src=&quot;http://localhost:5500/client/ishout.client.js&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;

    <script>
        ishout.on('alertchannel', function(data){
            alert(data.msg);
        });

        ishout.init();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Dashboard</h1>

        phuc<a href="/alert/?user=2">Alert (Hello)</a>

        <a href="/alert/?user=3">Alert (Hello)</a>

</body>
</html>
```

And when I inspect

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Home</title>


</head>
<body>
&lt;script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:5500/socket.io/socket.io.js"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
&lt;script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:5500/client/ishout.client.js"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;

    <script>
        ishout.on('alertchannel', function(data){
            alert(data.msg);
        });

        ishout.init();
    </script>


    <h1>Dashboard</h1>

        phuc<a href="/alert/?user=2">Alert (Hello)</a>

        <a href="/alert/?user=3">Alert (Hello)</a>


</body>
```

[Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4q1r.png)

Comment: Can you show your full template and view that renders it?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with that - can you post the rendered HTML?

Comment: updated. check please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the tag is returning HTML that is getting escaped, so the browser is rendering it as text inside the body instead of as real HTML in the `<head>`.

Turn off autoescape around the tag:

```
{% autoescape off %}
    {% ishout_js %}
{% endautoescape %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are including each of those js files, and you want it rendered and interpreted as html script tags, try making it a template file `_ishout_includes.html` instead. You don't need to change the contents of the file at all.

From there, use the [`{%include%}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#include) tag. It would look like

`{% include _ishout_includes.html%}`